# Zip folder exclude some folders

Tags: command-line, zip

I'm trying to backup my www-folder but hidden folders like .config inside www are added to the backup. I want to exclude the folder "backups" and all folders (and files) starting with a dot.

Current code:

```
zip -r /var/www/backups/site/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M).zip /var/www -x "*backups*" "*.*" "*/.*"
```

Comment: Crossposted at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571281/zip-folder-exclude-some-folders

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
zip -r --exclude=*backups* --exclude=*/.* /var/www/backups/site/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M).zip /var/www
```